# webgl-noise has wrong effect on android device

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I use webgl noise to create perlin noise . 
The shader run perfect on OpenGL Shader Builder in MAC.
But on Android device , The random noise because ordered.
Fragment Shader:

```
uniform float time; // Used for texture animation

varying vec3 v_texCoord3D ;

vec3 mod289(vec3 x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 mod289(vec4 x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 permute(vec4 x) {
    return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
}

vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
{
    return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
}

float snoise(vec3 v)
{
    const vec2  C = vec2(1.0/6.0, 1.0/3.0) ;
    const vec4  D = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);

    // First corner
    vec3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy) );
    vec3 x0 =   v - i + dot(i, C.xxx) ;

    // Other corners
    vec3 g = step(x0.yzx, x0.xyz);
    vec3 l = 1.0 - g;
    vec3 i1 = min( g.xyz, l.zxy );
    vec3 i2 = max( g.xyz, l.zxy );

    //   x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxx;
    //   x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
    //   x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
    //   x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
    vec3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;
    vec3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy; // 2.0*C.x = 1/3 = C.y
    vec3 x3 = x0 - D.yyy;      // -1.0+3.0*C.x = -0.5 = -D.y

    // Permutations
    i = mod289(i);
    vec4 p = permute( permute( permute(
                                       i.z + vec4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0 ))
                              + i.y + vec4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0 ))
                     + i.x + vec4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0 ));

    // Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
    // The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
    float n_ = 0.142857142857; // 1.0/7.0
    vec3  ns = n_ * D.wyz - D.xzx;

    vec4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p * ns.z * ns.z);  //  mod(p,7*7)

    vec4 x_ = floor(j * ns.z);
    vec4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_ );    // mod(j,N)

    vec4 x = x_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
    vec4 y = y_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
    vec4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);

    vec4 b0 = vec4( x.xy, y.xy );
    vec4 b1 = vec4( x.zw, y.zw );

    //vec4 s0 = vec4(lessThan(b0,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
    //vec4 s1 = vec4(lessThan(b1,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
    vec4 s0 = floor(b0)*2.0 + 1.0;
    vec4 s1 = floor(b1)*2.0 + 1.0;
    vec4 sh = -step(h, vec4(0.0));

    vec4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;
    vec4 a1 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;

    vec3 p0 = vec3(a0.xy,h.x);
    vec3 p1 = vec3(a0.zw,h.y);
    vec3 p2 = vec3(a1.xy,h.z);
    vec3 p3 = vec3(a1.zw,h.w);

    //Normalise gradients
    vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
    p0 *= norm.x;
    p1 *= norm.y;
    p2 *= norm.z;
    p3 *= norm.w;

    // Mix final noise value
    vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);
    m = m * m;
    return 42.0 * dot( m*m, vec4( dot(p0,x0), dot(p1,x1),
                                 dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3) ) );
}

//
// main()
//
void main( void )
{
    float n = snoise(v_texCoord3D);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(n * 0.5 + 0.5), 1.0);
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
uniform float time;

/*
 * Both 2D, 3D and 4D texture coordinates are defined, for testing purposes.
 */
varying vec3 v_texCoord3D;

void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = position;
    v_texCoord3D = vec3(position.xy, time);;
}
```

Draw code in android:

```
    glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeBuffer);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionLocation);
            glVertexAttribPointer(mInputTextureCoordinateLoation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(mInputTextureCoordinateLoation);
....

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

position is:
-1.0f, -1.0f, 
1.0f, -1.0f, 
-1.0f, 1.0f, 
1.0f, 1.0f,

texture coordinate is :
0.0f, 1.0f,
 1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 
1.0f, 0.0f,

Comment: *"The random noise because ordered"* ... uhm what ? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @LJ I guess OP reffers to the fact that this library that is supposed to generate random looking numbers on some android versions gives this kind of obviously non-random result: http://i.imgur.com/SIRqeZY.png